# How to correctly implement a dynamic array in C

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I have tried to write a short program in C that takes in space separated tokens from stdin, shuffles (permutes) the tokens and then prints the shuffles tokens to stdout. My shuffling algorithm works fine, the problem lies in the token parsing. I wanted to store the tokens in a dynamic string array so the program could support any number of tokens to be passed in through stdin. However, my current implementation of the dynamic array results in a segmentation fault whenever the array needs to be expanded. What am I doing incorrectly?

My Code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFERSIZE 33

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int i,j,k;
  i=j=k=0;
  int arrSize = 10;
  /* Temp fix */
  /* Get token count as command line argument */
  //if (argc==2) { sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&arrSize); }
  char  c='\0';
  char* t;
  char** datArr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*arrSize);
  //char* datArr[arrSize];
  char  token[BUFFERSIZE];
  while ( (c=getc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\0') {
    if(isspace(c)) {
      token[i] = '\0';
      i=0;
      if ( j >= arrSize) {
        arrSize *= 2;
        realloc(datArr, arrSize);
      }
      char* s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char[BUFFERSIZE]));
      strcpy(s,token);
      datArr[j++] = s;
    }
    else if(i+1 < BUFFERSIZE) {
      token[i++] = c;
    }
  }
  /* Permutate & Print */
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(i=0;i<j;++i) {
    k = rand()%(j-i);
    t = datArr[k];
    datArr[k] = datArr[j-i-1];
    datArr[j-i-1] = t;
  }
  for(i=0;i<j;++i) { printf("%s ",datArr[i]); }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** I know I did free the memory yet

Some sample input (to keep it card themed):

```
2C 3C 4C 5C 6C 7C 8C 9C 10C JC KC QC AC 2S 3S 4S 5S 6S 7S 8S 9S 10S JS KS QS AS
```

Comment: Do you know about `realloc` function?

Comment: I do not know about `realloc` function!

Comment: @awashburn time to fire up a doc on the C stdlib, it's *cool!*

Comment: I tried editing the code but this also results in a segmentation fault

Comment: `char  c='\0';` make that int.

Comment: You need to use `datArr = (char**)realloc(datArr,arrSize*sizeof(char*));`

Comment: @VaughnCato that fixed the program perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VaughnCato's comment on the original OP was the correct answer to the question.

"You need to use `datArr = (char**)realloc(datArr,arrSize*sizeof(char*));`"

Thanks VaughnCato!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFERSIZE 33

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int i,j,k;
  i=j=k=0;
  int arrSize = 10;
  /* Temp fix */
  /* Get token count as command line argument */
  //if (argc==2) { sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&arrSize); }
  char  c='\0';
  char* t;
  char** datArr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*arrSize);
  //char* datArr[arrSize];
  char  token[BUFFERSIZE];
  while ( (c=getc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\0') {
       // Just read the file
  }
}
```

I think that is an infinite loop.

getc() returns an int, not a char, so it should never stop reading the file, this is an infinite loop. That will exhaust memory, and eventually guarantee a seg fault.

I'd recommend changing `char  c='\0';` to `int c;` and apply the improvements in memory handling from there.

Comment: It is not an infinite loop; my program now works correctly. My question was answered by VaughnCato's comment on the OP.

Comment: Just because it seems to work, doesn't mean it hasn't got bugs. So have you changed the declaration fom 'char c;' to 'int c;'? If not, it still has a bug.

Comment: I edited my code taking in the advise of you and several others, changing `char c;` to `int c;`, adding `NULL` pointer checking, and correctly using the `realloc` function. It works well now, I haven't noticed any bugs. Thanks for your input.